# Load Balancing LDAP Connection in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, connection-pooling, spring-ldap

I have two LDAP servers that I wish to use in a round-robin fashion. This code as-written seems to always choose the first server. **How can I get it to choose evenly**?

```
private static LdapTemplate createLdapTemplate(String[] urls, String username, String password) {

    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrls(urls);
    contextSource.setBase(LDAP_SEARCH_BASE);

    // username is the same for both LDAP servers
    contextSource.setUserDn(username);
    contextSource.setPassword(password);

    contextSource.setPooled(true);
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
}
```

and I use the LDAP template like so:

```
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setTimeLimit(5000);

List ldapResultList = ldapTemplate.search("", filter.encode(), searchControls, (ContextMapper) o -> {
    // do things with result...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [spring-ldap reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/):

> If fail-over functionality is desired, more than one URL can be specified

Therefor you won't be able to achieve load balancing this way.

If you want to load balance between different LDAP server, what you should do instead, is to use a single LDAP server URL pointing to a loadbalancer (such as [HaProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)) placed in front of your LDAP servers and use it with `mode tcp`, and `balance roundrobin`.